# OWA printing nearly blank e-mails from Firefox

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook, printing, printer, outlook-web-access

Trying to deduce an issue in my office department: when printing e-mails from Outlook Web Access (Office365) using Firefox, some e-mails are coming out nearly blank (the headers--date/url/page numbers will print). It seems to be very random--some accounts print blank, others work.

Anyone experience this? Keep in mind we've tested with just basic text only e-mail bodies, and the same e-mails are printing just fine in both IE and Chrome. My best guess is that there's some issue with OWA and Firefox and that when OWA opens a new window to print a specific e-mail, there's some encoding issue that causes the problem.

Comment: Appears to be affecting several other people/organizations: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/251123.aspx